# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

В проекте написанном на ruby on rails установлна библиотека для jquery ui.

На следующем скрипте через консоль гугл хром выдает ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('.birthday1').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Полазив в интернете на форумах и поговорив с программистами, все говорят, что это из конфликта скриптов. Где то два раза запускается один и тот же скрипт или конфликт имен.

У меня вопрос следующий. Как и с помощью каких инструментов можно проверить где и что именно конфликтует? Проект очень большой, толком понять где этот скрипт конфликтует очень сложно. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Удостоверьтесь, что код datepicker'а (jquery-ui.[min.]js) загружен в страницу.

Comment: пробую... спасибо...

Comment: предполагаю что jquery грузится на страницу более 1 раза. Можно посмотреть в Хроме во вкладке Network загруженные на страницу js файлики. Либо поиском по html страницы

Comment: да. так и есть. Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была связана с конфликтом нескольких скриптов jquery. Через консоль хрома показала ошибку плагина. Удалил дублирующий и все стало на свои места.